# Limit through a series of products between inner products

Tags: sequences-and-series, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthonormal

Consider a Hilbert space $H$ and a complete orthonormal system $D$ in $H$. Let $h\in H$ and $\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a bounded succession in $H$ s.t.
\begin{equation}
(u_n,l)\rightarrow (u,l), \quad \forall l\in D.
\end{equation} I guess it should be true that 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{l\in D}(h,l)(u_n,l)=\sum_{l\in D} (h,l)(u,l)
\end{equation}
and for instance I have tried to apply the dominated convergence theorem but I can't prove each term is bounded by terms of a converging series...any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since $D$ is a complete orthonormal system, $h=\sum_l(h,l)l$, and thus
$$(h,u)=\sum_l(h,l)(u,l)$$
and similarly for $u_n$. So the problem is to show that $(h,u)=\lim_n(h,u_n)$.

---

**Hint**. By taking linear combinations, we have $(u_n,v)\to (u,v)$ for all $v\in\operatorname{span}D$, and $\operatorname{span}D$ is dense in $H$.

For $v\in\operatorname{span}D$, we have
$$|(h,u_n)-(h,u)|\leq\Vert h-v\Vert\Vert u_n\Vert+|(v,u_n)-(v,u)|+\Vert v-h\Vert\Vert u\Vert$$

Comment: The task of the exercise was actually to show that $u_n$ converges weakly to $u$ that exactly means
\begin{equation}
(h,u)=\lim_n(h,u_n) \quad \forall h\in H
\end{equation} 
and hence your hint comes back to my problem...

Comment: @WilliamTomblin Then, in my opinion, you made the exercise more complicated by using those formulas. I'll give some hints.

Comment: You are totally right: I had complicated the situation! Thanks a lot!